# How Does Prolog print out 2 lists as one list, without any append code?

Tags: list, prolog, union, member

I have the following code, which is apparently the standard way to show the union between 2 lists:

```
union([Head|Tail],List2,Result) :- 
    member(Head,List2),  union(Tail,List2,Result).
union([Head|Tail],List2,[Head|Result]) :- 
    \+ member(Head,List2), union(Tail,List2,Result).
union([],List2,List2).
```

and on the following input:

```
union([a,b,c,d,2,3], [b,c,3,99], Result).
```

will give me the following output:

```
Result = [a,d,2,b,c,3,99] ? 

yes
```

My question is, How does prolog do this? List2 is never changed throught the recursive calls, but at the end, it prints out all elements that make the union between the 2 original lists.

Please help me understand this code.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

let's assume that you ask union([1,2],[2],R).

according to the first rule, union([1|[2]],[2],R) would be true if
 member(1,[2]) --> false
then prolog will check the second rule union([1|[2]],[2],[1|R]) will be true if
+member(1,[2]) --> true
and union([2],[2],R)

now, union([2|[]],[2],R) would be true (1st rule) if
member(2,[2]) -->true
and union([],[2],R)

union([],[2],R) would be true (3rd rule) if R=[2]

so R=[2] and therefore the first call to union returns [1|[2]] = [1,2]

a useful tool to find out "how prolog does it" is trace/0:

```
    2 ?- trace.
true.

[trace] 2 ?- union([1,2],[2],R).
   Call: (6) union([1, 2], [2], _G543) ? creep
   Call: (7) lists:member(1, [2]) ? creep
   Fail: (7) lists:member(1, [2]) ? creep
   Redo: (6) union([1, 2], [2], _G543) ? creep
   Call: (7) lists:member(1, [2]) ? creep
   Fail: (7) lists:member(1, [2]) ? creep
   Call: (7) union([2], [2], _G619) ? creep
   Call: (8) lists:member(2, [2]) ? creep
   Exit: (8) lists:member(2, [2]) ? creep
   Call: (8) union([], [2], _G619) ? creep
   Exit: (8) union([], [2], [2]) ? creep
   Exit: (7) union([2], [2], [2]) ? creep
   Exit: (6) union([1, 2], [2], [1, 2]) ? creep
R = [1, 2] .
```

all in all: List2 doesnt not change but the predicate does not return List2 either; it returns a list created by List2 and the unique elements of List1

Comment: so, when the program reaches the very base recursive call:

    union([],List2,List2).

it will start jumping back up, sending List2 up the chain to:

    union([Head|Tail],List2,[Head|Result])

and the [Head|Result] in the third parameter will construct Head with List2(Result)?

and continue to build the result, taking the Head of the lists on each recursive level as it goes up the chain?

Comment: yup, that's how it works, it builds the result from the end (as you would expect with the Head|Tail paradigm).

Comment: so for this to work, the "variables" in the "function call" union([Head|Tail],List2,[Head|Result]), must initialize left to right.

initially, we have a list, which gets broken down into 2 varaibels Head and Tails, Then we have a variable named List 2, then we have the thrid variable, which is constructed due to Head already exisiting.  If Head didnt exists in the last variable, what would happen?

How does progol differentiate between the 1st variable being a list break up and the thrird variable being a construct list?

Comment: prolog just tries to make the predicate true. That means that if a list is a free variable (such as your result list), prolog will try to make it fit a format that allows the predicate to be true. In this example by initializing it to List2 and constructing it as detailed before...

Comment: its a very strange and confusing language.

Comment: at first approche, maybe. Then it becomes natural and relaxing compared to languages where you have to explicit everything and his mother (for certain problems ofc)! try a nice tutorial like Learn Prolog Now maybe :)

Comment: Yes, it's notorily a rather difficult language to learn. But after the initial difficult, it's fascinating and can be very productive.

Comment: @jordan.peoples I do not see why they should initialize from left to right; the could initialize from right to left as well: the third arg is a list with at least one element, the second arg is a free variable, the first is a list with the same head as the third.

Comment: Fair enough thanosQR, i just suck with prolog.  I guess the predicate is just a "check" that deosnt really execute code, and ehatever follows the predicate is the code to be executed right? kind of like a function prototype in C+/C#?  just a check , and if its true, it will execute the code behind it?

Comment: @jordan.peoples well, some code would be executed but that depends on the prolog implementation and in most cases there is no need for the programmer to know what exactly happens. as Mog said, prolog tries to unify the arguments of the head of the predicate and then satisfy the predicate's body. maybe you are used to write in more imperative languages and prolog looks weird; that's natural :)

Answer (score 1):

The algorithm in work here is the following :

1) initialize the result to `List2`. This part is implemented thanks to :

```
union([], List2, List2).
```

2) go through `List1` and do the following for each item :
2a) add it to `Result` if the item is not in `List2`. That part is implemented thanks to this clause :

```
union([Head|Tail], List2, [Head|Result]) :- 
    \+ member(Head, List2),
    union(Tail, List2, Result).
```

2b) don't do anything if the item is in List2. That part is implemented thanks to this clause :

```
union([Head|Tail], List2, Result) :-
    member(Head, List2),
    union(Tail, List2, Result).
```

For step by step comprehension of the prolog execution, please refer to @thanosQR answer.

By the way, note that this predicate needs sets to return a good union, else, a duplicate in `List1` will stay a duplicate in `Result` (so will a duplicate in `List2`).

Answer (score 1):

That code it's actually rather inefficient, so we can't assume it as the 'standard way' to compute union. At first glance, there are 2 simple optimizations: avoid repeat the membership test, and use memberchk/2 instead of member/2. So we can rewrite it in the following way:

```
union([Head|Tail], List2, ResultT) :-
    (  memberchk(Head, List2)
    -> ResultT = Result
    ;  ResultT = [Head|Result] ),
    union(Tail, List2, Result).
union([],List2,List2).
```

The difference in performance is huge. With relatively small lists:

```
...
numlist(1, 10000, A),
numlist(5000, 10000, B),
union(A, B, C),
...
```

we pass from *62,532,499* inferences to *20,002* inferences, and the test doesn't force the evaluation of all alternatives (backtrack points from member): adding this we need *25,015,004* more inferences, albeit no more solution is available. Here the code from SWI-Prolog *lists* library:

```
%%  union(+Set1, +Set2, -Set3) is det.
%
%   True if Set3 unifies with the union of Set1 and Set2.
%   The complexity of this predicate is |Set1|*|Set2|
%
%   @see ord_union/3.

union([], L, L) :- !.
union([H|T], L, R) :-
    memberchk(H, L), !,
    union(T, L, R).
union([H|T], L, [H|R]) :-
    union(T, L, R).
```

It's similar to your version, please note the **cut** (!)

Comment: Wow, i didnt even know you can have variables and assignment in prolog. i will have to look into your new way to find the union.  It looks easier than the way i was originally doing it.

Comment: In Prolog the 'assignement' it's called unification, a concept related to 'logical' variables

Comment: It's not assignment, it's [unification](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unification), think of it as pattern matching :)